# Calculate PSNR, VMAF, SSIM using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, codec

I am trying to calculate PSNR, VMAF, SSIM using FFmpeg after I reencode to 10-bit H.265 codec but I keep getting an errors:
"An invalid or unaligned stack was encountered during an unwind operation"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDY3M.png

I am new to FFmpeg so I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the original being a .mkv file and the reencoded is .mp4. I am not changing anything such as the scale or bitrates, so that isn't my issue. I am getting my build from BtbN's shared for win-64 gbl license ([BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases)).
Any help would be appreciated. I have tried the below command lines.

1. `ffmpeg.exe -i videoToCompare.mp4 -i originalVideo.mp4 -lavfi libvmaf="model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl":log_path=vmaf_logfile.txt -f null -`
2. `ffmpeg -i distorted.mp4 -i original.mp4 -filter_complex libvmaf -f null -`
3. `ffmpeg -i encode.mp4 -i reference.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic[main]; [1:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic,format=pix_fmts=yuv420p,fps=fps=25/1[ref]; [main][ref]libvmaf=psnr=1:phone_model=1:log_fmt=json" -f null - > out.json;`

Comment: Try providing the full path in `model_path`, or put `vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl` in your working directory.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did as you recommended and got a little further but I still get an error "Filter libvmaf has an unconnected output". My current command is: ffmpeg.exe -i output.mp4 -i input.mp4 -lavfi libvmaf=model_path="model_path\vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl":log_path="log_path\vmaf_logfile" -report -f null
If I add the - after null it fails with the original error. I tried adding an output file but it just gives the error "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'file_name.'"